# How to have the same VS project with multiple .csproj files depending on the VS version?

Tags: visual-studio, projects-and-solutions, compatibility, csproj

Sometimes I've seen a solution that includes up to three .csproj files for each project in the solution. Something like this:

`Project.UI.2005.csproj`
`Project.UI.2008.csproj`
`Project.UI.2010.csproj`

and the same with `.sln` files:

`ProjectSolution.2005.sln`
`ProjectSolution.2008.sln`
`ProjectSolution.2010.sln`

So if you copy the solution and want to open it using *VS2005*, you just need to open `Project.UI.2005.csproj` or `ProjectSolution.2005.sln`.

**What is the best way of creating those 3 (or 2) files, in order to be able to open the same solution in multiple versions of Visual Studio?**

Maybe the only way of doing this is modifying manually the `.sln`/`.csproj`. If so:

**How can I modify those files correctly so I won't crash the solution?**

I want to do this because sometimes I develop applications using *VS2010* and when deploying the source code to my customers, they can't open it in *VS2008*, and then I have to do some tweaks.

**Note**:
I know there will be referencing and compiling problems if I use features only included in .NET Framework v4.0, or similar. Let's suppose all the projects in the solution are compiling under .NET Framework 2.0 (*specified in the project properties*).

Comment: Are you looking for a better way than the one you described? I'm not entirely sure what sort of answers you're hoping to get here. There isn't really a "universal" project format that will open in *all* versions of VS, so you're pretty much stuck with multiple .csproj files.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Thanks for your answer. I know there isn't something 'magic' that allows me to do that. I edited my question (in bold). I'm looking for a way of creating those files without creating the solution in VS2005, opening (and backing up) with VS2008, and the same with 2010, or without copying & paste the .csproj and .sln manually and editing it in a text editor.

Comment: Erm, maybe I'm a little dense, but it sounds to me like you *are* asking for a magic solution. You don't want to save the file in each version of VS, and you don't want to edit the .csproj file manually using a text editor. That doesn't leave you with many options outside the magical realm. Maybe someone else knows something I don't, though. I've been wrong before.

Comment: Let's see. I don't mind modifying manually the .csproj/.sln file, but if that's the only option, then a good reference for doing this would be good so I won't crash the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally ended developing a small application do to this.
I'm still testing it, but it is working good so far.

All you need to do is, select the `.sln` file you want to convert, and specify the versions involved in the conversion, and it will do all the work for you.

If you have a **VS 2010** project:

- Solution (`Solution.sln`)

  - Project_1 (`Project_1.csproj`)
  - Project_2 (`Project_2.csproj`)

and you want downgrade the version (to 2008), it will keep those files, and also create:

- `Solution.2008.sln`

  - `Project_1.2008.csproj`
  - `Project_2.2008.csproj`

And you will be able to open `Solution.2008.sln` with **Visual Studio 2008** without problems.

As soon as I finish it, I'll share executables and sources here.

Comment: Twelve years later...